# how to make tween work normally?

Tags: java, repaint, tween

I am new to Tween, so i made the frame with 1 picture and tried to move it with Tween. Code:

```
public class Fram extends JFrame {

    public Fram() {
        setSize(700, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(new Panol());

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Fram();
    }

    public class Panol extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        Imag img;
        Rectangle r;
        TweenManager tm;
        Tween tween;
        Timer time;
        boolean t;

        public Panol() {

            tm = new TweenManager();
            img = new Imag(new ImageIcon(
                    "C:/Djokix/JAVA/SlideProba/src/AL/Ludi Durenmatt.png"),
                     10, 10, 100, 100);

            Tween.registerAccessor(Imag.class, new ParticleAccessor());

            Tween.to(img, ParticleAccessor.POSITION_XY, 100).target(200, 300)
                    .ease(Quad.INOUT).delay(1000)
                    .start(tm);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            g.drawImage(img.getImg(), (int) img.x, (int) img.y, (int) img.w,
                    (int) img.h, null);

            tm.update(1);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

The movement works but the repaint does not, so the picture leaves the trail of images along the way.

If someone knows what is the problem please help!

Comment: i just added the line super.paint(g) and it works!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Happy to be of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repaint()` does not clear the JPanel, it simply indicates that the paint method needs to be called again. In your paint method, you should clear the background before drawing.

I would set a background (white or black) with `setBackground(Color.BLACK);` in the JPanel constructor and then call `super.paint(g)` at the top of your paint method. You probably also don't need to call repaint in your paint method.